# mysql service not working on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

Problem detected!

```
Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56"!
```

MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
    or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: Change port of skype or change port in config of xampp control panel

Comment: change of port of skype??

Comment: yes because sometime skype use the same port number.

Answer (score 0):

open xampp control panel from tray maximize it then go to Config at the top right then Service and Port Settings here you can change the port number and save it remember to restart the services as well also check skype port sometime it cause the problem as well due to same port number is used by them.